# Matlab - Symbolic matrix ranks different after vpa application

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-computation

Recently I have encountered the following paradox (in my mind at least).

I tried to evaluate the rank of a symbolic matrix in Matlab (not really sure if `rank()` works as intended in the symbolic case, but anyway), but in order to simplify the coefficients resulting from the calculations, I used `vpa()` in the matrix.

What I noticed is that, after using `vpa` command, the matrix suddenly became a full rank matrix.

Has anyone had any previous experience with something similar to what I described? Which one should I trust?

Comment: `vpa` rounds all symbolic expressions to a certain number of digits, such rounding errors may influence your result.

Comment: I know that, but the weird thing is that the matrix contains symbolic expressions among variables only, all  multiplied by the same constant, i.e

K = ( constant ) * [f(x,y,z)]

Comment: Having the matrix I would further try to investigate, otherwise it's just blind guessing.

Comment: I tried working with removing the constant parameter, leaving just the symbolic expressions in the matrix elements. Vpa application has the following effect( showing some indicative changes ):

Before:
$$
\begin{matrix}
(x1 - x2)^2\\
(x1 - x2)*(y1 - y2)\\
(x1 - x2)*(z1 - z2)\\
\end{matrix}
$$

After:

$$
\begin{matrix}
(x1 - 1.0*x2)^2\\
(x1 - 1.0*x2)*(y1 - 1.0*y2)\\
(x1 - 1.0*x2)*(z1 - 1.0*z2)\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Based on your information I am unable to reproduce the problem. Try to create a [mcve].